# adding facets to extruded text

Tags: modeling, polycount

I am trying to convert extruded text letters to a low poly version (see image). I can extrude the text but even though I've been playing around with the decimate modifier, I haven't been able to get the desired results. I am still new to blender so any advice on how to achieve this look would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

[image]

Comment: @MartyFouts: You can fix the image link by removing the `!` in front of the link, just FYI.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin I approved your edit but something went wrong and another reviewer has to approve it.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos: Using the built-in image tool _does_ save your image to an external site: [i.stack.imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com). But it still enables users to view the image directly on the post (visually equivalent of embedding it), if the correct image-link syntax is used. In this case, it wasn't correct, because it provided a link to [imgur.com](https://imgur.com), not [i.stack.imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com).

Answer (score 1):

Once you've converted your letters to meshes, you can first display the *wireframe* in the *Viewport Overlays* panel:

[image]

Then select your letter and in *Edit* mode, select alla and press <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve* to simplify the topology (set the *Angle* value in the *Operator* box):

[image]

Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to triangulate the topology:

[image]

You can also give your object a *Decimate* modifier/*Collapse* mode and play with the *Ratio* value:

[image]

You can add some edges with the knife if necessary.

In *Edit* mode, go into the *Select panel > Select Random*, choose the *Ratio* value in the *Operator* box in order to select more or less vertices, and move the selected vertices on the Z axis:

[image]

Here is the kind of result you get:

[image]